# git rebase, resolve all conflicts manually

Tags: git

When on `feature` branch I use `git rebase master`, then a lot code is replaced automatically with code from `master`, and I get only one merge conflict. But those branches differ a lot, and I would expect more conflicts. Also files created before on `feature` (which does not exist on `master`) are removed.

Is there a way to look into all these changes, compare them and choose the ones I need. And only then finish rebasing.

Comment: You mean like interactive merge conflicts solving? Some IDE has very nice UI for that (e.g. PHPStorm https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/resolving-conflicts.html#distributed-version-control-systems)

Comment: If you want to only chose specific changeset, rebase is the wrong tool. You may be interested in [git cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files are not missing. Your `rebase` hasn't reached the point yet to apply those files. You only see one merge conflict now, once that it resolved and you continue, more may pop up.

As in the context of a `rebase`, you start from the head of the source branch, and all the commits of your target branch are applied one by one on it.

If a merge conflict arises, `rebase` stops to ask you to resolve the merge conflict. You have to fix them as they come one by one, and then continue the rebase each time a conflict occurs by marking the afflicted files as solved via:

```
git add <resolved file>
```

and then running:

```
git rebase --continue
```

until all the conflicts are resolved.

In a best case scenario all the changes are applied without any conflicts.

If in doubt, you can always hit

```
git rebase --abort
```

to get back to your feature branch as it was before you started the `rebase`.

There's not a real way to look at your changes as one during a `rebase`. You can do that beforehand

```
git diff <branchname>
```

If a `rebase` gets overly complicated, I like to use `git merge` as then you see all the changes (and conflicts) at once as you may expect. That might be easier to resolve for you.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I didnt realize that git rebase --continue goes into next commit and that was the reason, I thought I should get all at once, for some reason...

Comment: @andriejka If that solved your question, please feel free to mark the answer as accepted. That's the stackoverflow way of saying thank you :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I wasnt aware of this, just did it, thanks